# Bootstrap 3 Mobile Forms auto-resize not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I hate CSS and all of things about it, I've trouble which I think basically for experienced developers.

I have form which have 2 fields, and code is below:

```
<body class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                  <form ng-submit="logIn(user)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                      <div class="login-form">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="email" class="input form-control login-field ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-email" placeholder="E-posta" ng-model="user.email">
                              <label class="login-field-icon fui-user"></label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="password" class="input form-control login-field ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Parola" ng-model="user.password">
                              <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock"></label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
  </body>
```

And here is my `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I check I see correctly called all files from browser, problem not about it.

The result form elements style which I expect like this:

[image]

But I see this:

[image]

Forms not resized. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you refreshed after resizing

Comment: yes I tried it but result wasn't changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suspect you are missing the [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) declaration in the `head` of your html

```
<head>
   ...
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

See the basic Bootstrap [template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) for everything that you need.

Comment: It's worked! I will accept your answer in 10 minutes because I can't now :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

**It uses the @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true.**

/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
    /* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }



@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

look at this link [Media Query](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)